# Subtracting datetimes in pandas always equals 0

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

two columns of dates in my dataframe. The first column is df['schedule_day'] and the second is df['appointment_day']. I am trying to create another column that will be the different between these two. However, when I do the subtraction, the new column just has 0 for each answer.

The original data has these dates as strings and I convert them to datetime objects before doing the subtraction and the result is still a datetime object. 
Here is the code I have used so far.

```
df = pd.read_csv('noshowappointments-kagglev2-may-2016.csv')

df['schedule_day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['schedule_day'])
df['appointment_day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['schedule_day'])

df['difference'] = df['schedule_date'] - df['appointment_date']
```

When I inspect the dtypes the after the initial read they are object / string types. After I do the conversion they are datetime64[ns].

I also tried to split the date and time apart into seperate columns to do the subtractions but I still just get 0 days for each row.

Comment: We can't see the data that you're working with. Please include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: are you sure your columns are DateTime?? and how about the correct format?

Comment: This is a typo: `df['appointment_day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['schedule_day'])` should be `df['appointment_day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['
df['appointment_day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['schedule_day'])'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small copy error, you use  df['schedule_day'] for both conversions

```
df['schedule_day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['schedule_day'])
df['appointment_day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['schedule_day'])
```

Change to:

```
df['schedule_day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['schedule_day'])
df['appointment_day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['appointment_day'])
```

Comment: Martin, thank you so much! I feel so silly not seeing that. roganjosh, I am sorry it was not clear enough. I thought describing the types at each step through was enough. Next time I need to ask something I will attempt to be even more clear. Thank you for letting me know I was not clear enough.